# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'

Tags: python, error-handling, module, googletrans

the code (from googletrans import Translator) brings up the following error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/cadeylange/Documents/python_work/Personal/frequently_used_words.py",
>   line 2, in <module>
>       from googletrans import Translator ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans' [Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1] [cmd:
>   ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u',
>   '/Users/cadeylange/Documents/python_work/Personal/frequently_used_words.py']]
>   [dir: /Users/cadeylange/Documents/python_work/Personal] [path:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]`

I've double-checked that the googletrans has been installed successfully using pip and it has. I cannot think of why the code won't work, I've tried importing it using different expressions including the basic "import googletrans" statement. Could anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the traceback shows, you're running Python 3 on a Linux box, right? Have you tried installing the module with pip3, what should make it availble for Python 3.

Comment: hi, yes sorry i did use pip3 when I originally installed it as I am using python3. I'm currently working on a MacBook pro running through the terminal

Comment: Was my first idea and works on my box, no other idea at the moment, sorry